# Can I compress Web Service Request and response using mod_gzip module of apache?

Tags: php, web-services, apache

Can i compress **web service** request and response using **mod_gzip** module of **apache**?

Comment: Why would you want to compress request?

Comment: As I think by compressing web service, i can utilize the band width. do you have any suggestion for it?

Comment: You cannot compress the *request* on the server. The client will have to send a compressed request, otherwise it's kinda pointless.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/56700/is-it-possible-to-enable-http-compression-for-requests

Comment: @deceze :: thanks for your answer. But what about the web service response? can I compress it?

Answer (score 1):

$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/api/wsdl",array('compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP, "trace" => 1));

by adding compression type, got response in compressed format.

Answer (score 0):

The server can compress the response, if the client stated in its request that it can deal with compressed responses (e.g. the client sends `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` in its request).

The server cannot compress the request, that's pointless. The client will have to compress the request before it sends it to the server; but the client cannot know whether the server can handle a compressed request, so typical browser clients do not do so. If you have an API which serves specific clients, the client can compress the request and the server can decompress it simply by agreement.

[mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) can be configured to compress and decompress both ways.
Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/56700/is-it-possible-to-enable-http-compression-for-requests.